# Can I have a function in Excel that changes a sum once the value of a certain column exceeds a specified value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

For my accounts, I can claim certain amounts of mileage back against tax:
£0.45/mile up to 10,000 miles
£0.25/mile after 10,000 miles

In my spreadsheet, I have a column for miles covered per job (I). To work out the flat rate travel cost (column J) I multiply the cell in I by 0.45. (=SUM(I2*0.45))

Can I have a formula where the cell in I is multiplied by 0.25 after the total value of I exceeds 10,000?

I don't know whether this is possible/practical

Comment: Do you mean to apply the multiplication of 0.25 from the row where the sum of column I up to that row would exceed given number, or would the multiplication apply (change) for all previous rows as well?

Comment: No. So in "column I" I have total miles covered per job
In "column J" I work out the flat rate mileage cost (0.45 per mile upto 10,000 then 0.25 from miles 10001 upwards). At the moment in column J for cell J2 I have =SUM(I2*0.45)
What I want is that the flat rate mileage cost (i.e., the multiplier in J) is 0.45 until the total miles traveled (column I total) exceeds 10,000 then the flat rate mileage (i.e., the multiplier in J) cost switches to 0.25

Comment: Than you can mark this answered by clicking the green `✓` next to Vetuka's answer.

Comment: is it the first job that crosses the 10,000 miles that where the portion over 10,000 goes to .25, or is the portion over 10,000 spread out over all jobs based on their portion of the total mileage driven?

Comment: The first job that crosses 10,000 miles goes to 0.25, so all jobs from 0 to 9999 miles are at the 0.45p rate

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
=IF(SUM(I:I*0.45)>10000,SUM(I:I*0.25),SUM(I:I*0.45))
```

Put the following on I1 cell

```
=IF(SUM(I2:I10000*0.45)>100000,SUM(I2:I100000*0.25),SUM(I2:I100000*0.45))
```

Comment: Thank you- It is the value of the whole column of I rather than just I2 that needs to be above 10,000 for it to change to *0.25

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for your help. I think It still is not working:
The data runs from I2 down. To test it, I put 9999 miles in I2 and it correctly multiplies by 0.45. I put 1 (the 10,000th mile) in I3 and it correctly multiplies by 0.45, but when I add 1 to I4 (the 10,001st mile) it multiplies that by 0.45 (should be *0.25) and the data multiplications by 0.45 from data in I 2&3 change completely (e.g., I3 is then multiplied by 0.9(

Comment: @TomLitch I thought your data was starting from I3. Can you put the revised formula on I1 cell and test it? It is pretty simple formula, should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this task.  Option 1 is to use a running total, and when that running total crosses over the 10,000 threshold, you use a blended rate which is equivalent of 0.45 for the portion still within the 10K limit + 0.25 for the portion over the 10K limit.  All subsequent jobs get the 0.5 rate applied to them.

See concepts below.

In order to do this I used a helper column to hold the running total.  I placed that in column L since you said you wanted the cost in column J.  Personally I would prefer the cost to be at the far right with the helper columns in between.

In L5 place the following formula:

```
=I5
```

In L6 place the following formula and copy down as needed:

```
=I6+L5
```

In K5 use the following formula:

```
=IF(L5<=10000,0.45,IF(L5>10000,10000*0.45+(L5-10000)*0.25))
```

In K6 use the following formula and copy down:

```
=IF(L6<=10000,0.45, IF(AND(L5<10000,L6>10000),((10000-L5)/I6)*0.45+((L6-10000)/I6)*0.25,0.25))
```

In J5 place the following formula and copy down:

```
=K5*I5
```

Option 2 is to proportion the 10,000 miles at the higher rate bases on how many miles were driven for that job.  While this sounds more complicated, it is more fare for what each job gets billed.  Note in the example below, that the inputs and totals are the same, but the amount each job is billed between option 1 and option 2 is different.

For option 2 to work, I made to working columns where I broke the portion of low miles and high miles for each job. In order to determine what portion of the low miles a job would get it was simply:

```
miles for job / all miles driven * 10000
```

So in K14 use the following and copy down to determine the portion of the low mileage for the job:

```
=I14/SUM($I$14:$I$18)*10000
```

In L14 us the following and copy down to determine the portion of the high mileage for the job:

```
=I14-K14
```

Then place your low and high mileage rate in a cell somewhere.  I chose cells M14 and N14 respectively.

To determine your cost for a job, multiply your low mileage by low mileage rate and similar for high mileage.  In cell J14 I used the following formula and copied down:

```
=K14*$M$14+L14*$N$14
```

[image: POC]

On a side note, I would highly recommend placing your rates and your 10K threshold amount in a cell and referring to those cells with your formula instead of hard coding.  That way if there rates change or the threshold changes, you just need to change the value in a cell instead of editing a whole bunch of formulas.

Below is my preferred layout:

[image]

If you want to avoid the helper columns you can but back substituting the reference cells into the final cost formula.

When you do, you can get something that looks like this:

[image]

Note the formulas in J2, J3 copied down, and J14 copied down are as follows:

```
J5
=IF(SUM($I$5:I5)<=$N$4,$O$4,IF(SUM($I$5:I5)>$N$4,$N$4*$O$4+(SUM($I$5:I5)-$N$4)*$P$4))*I5

J6
=IF(SUM($I$5:I6)<=$N$4,$O$4, IF(AND(SUM($I$5:I5)<$N$4,SUM($I$5:I6)>$N$4),(($N$4-SUM($I$5:I5))/I6)*$O$4+((SUM($I$5:I6)-$N$4)/I6)*$P$4,$P$4))*I6

J14
=I14/SUM($I$14:$I$18)*$N$4*$O$4+(I14-I14/SUM($I$14:$I$18)*$N$4)*$P$4
```

Comment: This looks like the answer! Thanks so much!